# Can I turn the word vocabulary into a countable noun?

Tags: nouns

Can I turn the word vocabulary into a countable noun?

For example:

> She is an exquisite student who possesses **a considerable passive
>   vocabulary** that enables her to understand the most of the lesson

Comment: "most of the lesson" not "the most".

Comment: The word vocabulary in  particular sentence would not take a plural. But the answers below are good. Where have you seen that it is not countable?

Comment: Are you asking about the use of the indefinite article **a** as in *She speaks **an** impeccable English?*  We don't have "extensive vocabulary" but "**an** extensive vocabulary".  But "Class, this week, we will review vocabulary".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo    So, if I got your point, if it's someone's stock of words of some language in his personal memory, I should use "a/an", but if it's just some collection of words of some language, then it's just uncountable "vocabulary", right?

Comment: @Lambie: "Where have you seen that it is not countable?" - I just thought that _vocabulary_ could be both countable and non-countable - just like _language_.

Comment: *This cake is made with **flour***.  There, "flour" refers to the substance generally. *The bakery uses a number of **flours**, among them rye flour, wheat flour, buckwheat flour, and rice flour.* There, **flours** refers to varieties of flour. The same principle can be applied to **vocabulary**.  The word can refer in general terms to the set of words possessed by any and every speaker of a language. *The chimp Panbanisha had a 3000-word vocabulary.* Or it can refer to some circumstance involving differences among specific vocabularies, of different speakers, say, or of different groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to ask this is if *vocabulary* can be the plural *vocabularies*.  Your spell checker should already tell you this is a valid word.  Some examples:

> One solution to the final problem presented in the previous section is to organise the terms into a taxonomy. Taxonomic **vocabularies** are systems in which concepts are related using hierarchical relations ...
>
> ... the NAA which has, in addition to photographs, manuscripts, field notes, sound tapes, linguistic data, and other documents including **vocabularies** of Indian and Inuit languages and drawings.

*Vocabularies* appears mostly in academic and technical writing, and would not normally be used in casual conversation.  The singular is also slightly formal, but more common:

> Those who dive deep into the culinary world learn that chefs have developed **a** sophisticated **vocabulary** to talk about food and food preparation.
>
> She has **a** good **vocabulary**, but her grammar needs work.

Answer (score 3):

**vocabulary** can be pluralized.

> The vocabularies of elementary school students in rural and urban districts were compared.

Answer (score 0):

`vocabulary` already **is** a countable noun.

The definition of vocabulary, is a collection of words. For ease of understanding, try mentally replacing "words" with "fruit". Any grammar rules that apply to collections, also apply to vocabulary. Consider the following sentences, and see if they still make sense to you if you replace "collection" and "apple" with "vocabulary" and "word":

Can you have two kinds of collections? Yes, you can have a collection of apples, and a collection of oranges. Can you have two collections of apples? Certainly; this is my collection of green apples, and over there is my collection of red apples. How big is your collection? My collection has 314 apples in it.